# convert two dimentional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2 dimensional array:

```
const keys = [
    ['a'],
    ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    ['X', 'Y']
]
```

And I want to convert it to this format:

```
const output = [
    ['a', 'one', 'X'],
    ['a', 'one', 'Y'],        
    ['a', 'two', 'X'],
    ['a', 'two', 'Y'],         
    ['a', 'three', 'X'],
    ['a', 'three', 'Y']
]
```

The order of the output array is of importance. 
I have tried several approaches (recursive functions, a function that determines the fill length of the output and then fills in each position, etc.) but none of them seem to work...

Any help (code or concepts) would be much appreciated as this seemingly simple problem is giving me an headache.

Comment: You want all combinations of each sub-array?

Comment: Yep... in the right order. So pretty much as we would be counting. However, in this case not all digits can count up to the same amount (if that makes any sense)

Comment: var data = [['a'], ['one', 'two', 'three'], ['X', 'Y']],
result = data.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []));

console.log(result); . u will get your answer.

Comment: @adiga Thanks... did not know it was called "Cartesian product".

Comment: @Krunal Shah thnx. works

Comment: @KrunalShah, the answer could be from me ... ;-)

Comment: yes ;) @NinaScholz